# Android bluetooth cancel bond

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a Android where I connect to a bluetooth printer, print something and then I need to close the connection.

So currently I connect and print, but I'm unable to disconnect.

I interrupt the client and server thread, unregister the broadcastReceiver but when I try to connect again it fails to discover the device.

Is there a method I should call to destroy the bond? not unpair the devices, just the bond between then so that I can reconnect and discover it again.

Unregister the receiver:

```
unregisterReceiver(blueToothBroadcastReceiver);
```

Kill the server and client threads:

```
if (serverServer != null) {
            serverServer.interrupt();
        }

        if (clientServer != null) {
            clientServer.interrupt();
        }

        this.isOpen = false;
        Bluetooth.isConnected = false;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you use `mySocket.close();`?

Comment: BluetoothSocket mmSocket is in the client thread, is it not killed on clientServer.interrupt():

Comment: oky I explicitly close the socket, still the same

Comment: Tried all this? `mmOutputStream.close();
            mmInputStream.close();
            mmSocket.close();`

Comment: Yes, tried them all, is there something I'm missing perhaps? somewhere I need to say its closed so start from the beginning and reconnect?